How can i change the screen orientation to Landscape in Selenium C#?
I am testing a webMobile version of a website. I need to change the screen orientation to landscape, but I can not find any appropriate code.
Here is what I did:
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]').setAttribute('content', 'width=device-height, height=device-width, initial-scale=1');");

var frame = wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.Id("gameFrame")));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame);

var elem = wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".buttonLabel.leftButtonLabel")));

((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elem);

if (elem.Displayed)
{
    action.MoveToElement(elem).Click().Perform();
}

This changed to landscape but it only changed the viewport, and the elements became not interactable.
Do you have any solution for this in C# Selenium?

I think "the elements became interactable" is the problem to solve. Can you [edit] your question to include the C# code? We need an [repro], otherwise we cannot help you.

BTW, it the viewport changes, then you've accomplished what you want. Switching the orientation is not instantaneous. I bet you need to use an explicit wait before interacting with the elements on the page after an orientation change.

I just edited the post with the C# code included, so i tried to click on the elements with jsexecutor as well but still it is not clicking on it. Also when already the viewport is in landscape, when you are in devTools and want to inspect the element it still shows you the portrait image in blue color, but the screen is in landcape already, so i thought i am missing something here.
